# What should we do when we accidentally kill an animal?

Tags: rituals, customs, prayaschitta

Would like to know what pratikriya (remedy) should we do if we accidentally kill an animal e.g., a car hitting a cow or deer accidentally or car running over a snake?

Also, in the case of a vehicle killing an animal should we change the vehicle?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  Personal advice questions are not allowed on this site, so I'm closing your question.  If you want to edit your question so that it's less about your personal situation and more general, like "What should be done to remedy accidentally killing an animal?" or something like that, then it may be more acceptable for the site.

Comment: I'd be interested in a more general version of your question (along the lines suggested).

Comment: I don't think this is fully an opinion based question. The questioner wants to clear his doubt regarding what is written in texts regarding parikara/prashchit for an accidental killing like this. There are various texts which have a say about such things, eg, i have heard that if a person kills a cat then he has to donate a cat made of gold.

Comment: More examples: There is also written in texts regarding what one has to do if he kills a cow or a brahmin. eg, Gautam rishi killed a cow, Lord Balarama killed a  Brahmin, and they both had a way to do prashchit.

Comment: modified my question to fit the rules, thanks

Comment: OK, I'm reopening your question.

Comment: My opinion is if the act of killing the animal was purely an accident, then sincere remorse and praying to the Lord for forgiveness, should be sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

The Smritis give us penances for all sorts of sins committed.Some even  give you penances for accidentally killing  animals.But many of these penances will look outdated or at least will be difficult to perform for someone living in this age.

In any case here are a few of them:

> By [consciously] killing a frog, mongoose, crow, cat, boar, mouse or a
>   dog, a twice-born person should perform a great penance extending over
>   sixteen days
>
> **By [unconsciously] killing a dog**, one should zealously drink milk for
>   three nights. (7)
>
> **by [unknowingly] killing a cat or a mongoose**, one should wend a way a
>   Yojan [in length]. By killing a horse, a twice-born person should
>   perform a hard austerity extending over twelve [days]. (8)
>
> To take clarified butter is the purification [enjoined for destroying]
>   flowering [plants]. **By killing, by mistake, [a cow], one should
>   perform the Chandrayana* and the Paraka.**
>
> **Usana Smriti,Chapter 9.**

BTW,Usana Smriti refers to the Smriti composed by Daityaguru Sukra and is one of the major 18 Smritis.

So,for [accidentally killing a dog](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17321/killed-a-dog-puppy-by-accident-feelin-uncomfortable-please-help-me) the remedy seems to be living on milk only for three nights.