# By killing mosquito/bedbugs take us to hell?

Tags: karma, practice, other-religions

Some castes don't consume meat because of some religious traditions and practices. But knowingly or unknowingly we all have killed insects.

For example, even microorganisms that enables curd from milk which we consume. So, indirectly we all have consumed non-veg.

Even plants also have lives in which we are taking it.

And night times, we definitely kill mosquitoes or bed bugs by spray/liquid or hands.

And during the walk, we may have stamped on ants as well.

So, will we go to hell? Is it a serious crime?

Comment: Not accurate to what I want to understand

Comment: duplicate - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/is-it-wise-to-kill-an-insect-just-because-it-is-bothering-you/9177#9177 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27484/do-farmers-have-the-right-to-kill-pests/27485#27485

Comment: Not really I am talking about killing mosquitoes not pests

Answer (score 1):

Nothing As such mentioned in Bhagavata Puran which mentions the list of Hells. The nearest I could find is **Pranarodha** which states

> Some Brahmins, Kshatriyas and Vaishyas (merchant caste) indulge in the
>   sport of hunting with their dogs and donkeys in the forest, resulting
>   in wanton killing of beasts. Yamadutas play archery sport with them as
>   the targets in this hell.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naraka_(Hinduism))

Answer (score 1):

Killing bugs, insects, etc is not a sin. Mosquitoes inject malaria / dengue / chikanguniya virus. So its their strength Vs human strength. Many die due to these diseases.

In Bhagvat Geetha, Krishna tells Arjuna not to think of relationship. If for justice you have to kill, go ahead and kill.

So to live without disease, you kill your enemy.

No sin at all.

Answer (score -1):

Everything that you do - right or wrong, good or bad, depends on your intention. So, if you were to have a negative intention, what you did would be bad. Conversely, if you had positive intentions, what you did would be good.

The gray area is being unintentional i.e. accidentally doing something. The Hindu mythology suggests that karma begins with intentions.

> The Vedas acknowledge the right intention as the basis of good karma and liberation.
> Source: [Hinduwebsite](https://www.hinduwebsite.com/divinelife/divinelaws4.asp)

Having said that, unintentional killing of bugs, mosquitoes, or other insects could be spared, you would not have bad karma. (Every time we breathe, walk, or sit someplace, we kill millions of microorganisms.) However, if you derive pleasure from doing so, you are intentionally hurting a life, and you have bad karma.

**Personally, I do not believe in the concept of heaven or hell. I believe in reincarnation and the fact that we pay our dues in this life itself.**