# Living creatures and sins

Tags: vedas, gods, philosophy, moksha, kali-yuga

I, myself have killed so many mosquitoes, pests in my life. Now, I have come to a thought that they too are beautiful expressions created by god. Every single being created by the supreme serves a purpose. I really really regret this and In fact I feel hard to live up with these sins. Higher perspective referring to this, good deeds for atonement, for forgiveness or liberation from this would really save a life. My deepest gratitude for the answer in advance.

Comment: There are many posts on this topic which you can refer to ..like one here -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9175/4732

Comment: More posts -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/27484/4732  and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/46539/4732

Comment: Arjuna killed hundreds of thousands of soldiers too and Krishna was responsible for that. Both are sinners according to your question?