# Is it a sin to kill a mosquito in Hinduism?

Tags: sin

If I kill mosquitoes in my room with an electric mosquito-killing racket, will that be considered a sin? Why?

Comment: Killing on its own is not a sin (e.g. eating meat is not a sin). Harming is, so as long as you are not torturing them, I don't see how this would be a sin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it wise to kill an insect just because it is bothering you](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/is-it-wise-to-kill-an-insect-just-because-it-is-bothering-you)

Comment: It's a little bit related to my question so I'll be really grateful if you answer for this specific question.

Comment: Hello! I feel they are quite the same. Can you please clarify more if it is a bit different?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HSE. Kindly visit [How Does a New User Get Started on HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se).

Comment: @Mr_Green It's about insects in general who are hopping in your apartment, mine is about mosquitoes who keep biting me

Comment: Mosquitoes, houseflies, cockroaches....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to Devi Bhagavatam it is a sin to kill mosquitoes. The reason is that Almighty has created mosquitoes to be like they are. They drink blood as it's part of their Swadharma.

> He who kills a black serpent on whose hood there is the lotus mark,
> lives in Sarpa Kunda for as many years as there are hairs on his body
> and he is bitten by serpents there and beaten by the servants of Yama
> and eats the excrescences of snakes and finally becomes born as a
> serpent. Then he becomes a man shortlived and having the cuticaneous
> disease and ringworm. And his death also comes out of snake-bite. He
> who kills mosquitoes and other small fanged-animals, that earn their
> substance rightly and pass so their lives, goes to Dams’a mas’a Kunda
> where he is eaten by mosquitoes and other fanged-creatures and lives
> there without food and crying, weeping, for as many years as the
> numbers of lives destroyed. Besides the Yama’s servants tie his hands
> and feet and beat him.
>
> **Book 9; Chapter 33**

Personally I was quite surprised when I had first read this passage.

Comment: LOL. That's too much ahimsa imho. Nice find tho!

Comment: I remember reading something similar in Garuda Purana. If you intentionally kill, then it's a sin.

Answer (score 0):

Mosquitos take your drops of blood and give bite marks, pain and disease.

I think it won't be a sin if you kill it in the second attempt

Make it fly away in the first attempt as a warning, and if it comes again to hurt you, then kill it for your self-defence

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HSE!! Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions on HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/17833). Further, kindly have a look at the [HSE HELP CENTER](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help), and then get started in here properly. Have an enriching journey ahead!

Comment: self-defence?? :D