# What does hinduism say about killing insects?

Tags: karma, dharma, rebirth

What does hinduism say about killing insects?Is it ok or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it wise to kill an insect just because it is bothering you](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/is-it-wise-to-kill-an-insect-just-because-it-is-bothering-you)

Comment: Besides the above one, there are several other very similar questions on the same topic. You may search the site with "insects"

Answer (score 1):

Hinduism says that it is impossible to avoid killing insects.

> Tuladhara said, ‘People regard the profession of agriculture to be
> sinless. That profession, however, is certainly frought with cruelty.
> The iron-faced plough wounds the soil and many creatures that live in
> the soil.’

**Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCLXII**

The best one can do is to minimize violence.

> Tuladhara said, ‘O Jajali, I know morality, which is eternal, with all
> its mysteries. It is nothing else than that ancient morality which is
> known to all, and which consists of universal friendliness, and is
> fraught with beneficence to all creatures. That mode of living which
> is founded upon **a total harmlessness towards all creatures or (in case
> of actual necessity) upon a minimum of such harm, is the highest
> morality.’**

**(Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCLXII)**

Answer (score 0):

This is what Lord Krishna says in Uddhava Gita

> A saintly person should step or place his foot on the ground **only
> after verifying with his eyes that there are no living creatures, such
> as insects, who might be injured by his foot.** He should drink water
> only after filtering it through a portion of his cloth, and he should
> speak only words that possess the purity of truth. Similarly, he
> should perform only those activities his mind has carefully
> ascertained to be pure.(SB 11.18.16)