# Killed a dog puppy by accident , feelin uncomfortable please help me

Tags: sin

I am a brahmin , today i was doing shiva ratri's upavas ,evening me and my family went to shiva temple everything was good till i returned home , once my family members stepped down of car i took my car somewhat forward to park it correctly , suddenly a small dog which was being chased by a group of 5-6 dogs came below my car and it died , i am feeling so uncomfortable , i love street dogs so much infact the dog which was killed by me accidentally  its mother was born infront of me with 4 other dogs , i take care of  7-8 street dogs daily , now the mother dog which i used to feed daily and it used to always follow me during my small walks is shouting on me , what should i do please help me

Comment: See my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17332/4732

Comment: This question is not an exact duplicate of the other..because here OP is asking specifically about dog..the other question is about some other animals but not dog..In anycase i have added an answer to the other question but my answer is answering this question more precisely than the other one..